# Using Django models in external python script

Tags: python, django

I was very confused today.

I was trying to use my django app models in my python script.

here is my approach

```
import os, sys

sys.path.append("/var/www/cloudloon/horizon")
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "openstack_dashboard.settings"
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

I was confused why its giving me

```
ImportError: Could not import settings 'openstack_dashboard.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): cannot import name auth
```

Upon checking I created a a file called creds that includes

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/var/www/cloudloon/horizon/; 
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=openstack_dashboard.settings; django-admin.py shell;
```

and from terminal window where creds file is located, I do

```
source creds
```

and from that django-admin.py shell, I could import any of my django app models without any errors.

Why it doesn't work in my python script?

I am done with Django, What I need to do is to create a python-daemon script that will access my django app models.

I am working with in Ubuntu 12.04 that has django 1.5

As I looking for solutions, I did this:

```
import os, sys

sys.path.append("/var/www/cloudloon/horizon")
sys.path.append("/var/www/cloudloon/horizon/openstack_dashboard")
# os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "settings"
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE",
                          "openstack_dashboard.settings")

print os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"]
for s in sys.path:
    print s

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

heres the output: http://paste.openstack.org/show/48787/

as you can see, the directory where settings.py is located are present on my sys.path, however, It was still unable to import openstack_dashboard.settings.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 32):

You need to write a [custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/custom-management-commands/), instead of doing these weird acrobatics.

Create a *module* called management (in other words, create a directory `management` and inside it create an empty `__init__.py` file) inside the directory of any app that you have listed in `INSTALLED_APPS`. So if you have `myapp`, you would create:

```
myapp
 |
 > management
 | | __init__.py
 > models.py
 > views.py
```

Then in the management directory, create another module `commands` and in it create a file which is the name of your command; for example `my_command.py`, like this:

```
myapp
 |
 > management
 | | __init__.py
 | | commands
 | | | __init__.py
 | | | my_command.py
 > models.py
 > views.py
```

In `my_command.py`, write this boilerplate code:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from myapp.models import MyModel

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Does some magical work'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        """ Do your work here """
        self.stdout.write('There are {} things!'.format(MyModel.objects.count()))
```

Once you save the file, you'll be able to do `python manage.py my_command` and it will have access to all your models and settings.

If you need to run it as a daemon, [Daniel Roseman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104349/daniel-roseman) wrote [`django-initd`](https://github.com/danielroseman/django-initd) which does exactly that. Once you have installed it:

```
from django.core.management.base import CommandError
from daemon_command import DaemonCommand
from myapp.models import MyModel

class Command(DaemonCommand):
    help = 'Does some magical work'

    def loop_callback(self, *args, **options):
        """ Do your work here """
        self.stdout.write('There are {} things!'.format(MyModel.objects.count()))
```

Once you have that done [from the github readme](https://github.com/danielroseman/django-initd):

```
The important parts of such a process are these:

    * it comes up automatically on server startup
    * it logs errors and information to a named location, which is configurable
    * if the process dies, it restarts itself straight away 

[...]

Run the command as normal, but pass one of --start, --stop or --restart to 
work as a daemon. Otherwise, the command will run as a standard application.
```

Comment: I had this as an answer previously, but the script is supposed to be a daemon, not a once off command.

Comment: It seems too difficult to implement with python-daemon.

Comment: Nice answer, didn't know about django-initd. This is how OP should do it, but I think OP has path issues.

Comment: The path issues will go away once he uses a management command.

Comment: This worked perfectly on Django 1.8. (None of the path setting and importing techniques suggested in other answers worked.)

Comment: Nicely explained. Thanks.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid after running setup.py of django-initd I am not able to import daemon_command, where am I going wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 11):

The below script should work provided that the layout of your project (and the path to your settings file) looks like this:

> /var/www/cloudloon/horizon/openstack_dashboard/settings.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os, sys

sys.path.append("/var/www/cloudloon/horizon")
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "openstack_dashboard.settings"
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

I believe the problem you're seeing is due to the arrangement of your project, or that you need to append another directory level to the `sys.path` call in the script.

Edit:

Looking at your github project, `horizon` and `openstack_dashboard` are on the same directory level. What you'd want to do is set your `sys.path` to one level higher:

```
sys.path.append("/var/www/cloudloon")
```

Comment: management command seems not a good idea for what I am trying to create. I need to create python-daemon script. Basically, to run python-daemon script, I need to run "python myscript.py run". Python management command is not good for it.

Comment: Using your code above, It gives me AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__file__'

Comment: @DjangoBot sorry, the setup_environ takes a module object, not a string. I've corrected the code snippet.

Comment: setup_environ seems have been deprecated since Django 1.4. DeprecationWarning: The 'setup_environ' function is deprecated, you likely need to update your 'manage.py'; please see the Django 1.4 release notes (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/)

Comment: @DjangoBot I've updated my answer, but it basically only says to check your project structure.

Comment: Still got no luck, regarding my project structure, you may look in my repo @ https://github.com/neumerance/iaas

Comment: @DjangoBot see my update. I'm hoping you don't have /var/www/cloudloon/horizon/horizon :P

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

```
from django.conf import settings
import myfolder.settings as app_settings

settings.configure(INSTALLED_APPS=app_settings.INSTALLED_APPS,DATABASES=app_settings.DATABASES)

import django
django.setup()

from myapp123.models import Sample
for s in Sample.objects.all():
    print(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution (inspired by http://blog.gabrielsaldana.org/using-django-models-in-external-python-scripts/):

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append( os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'MyDjangoProject'))
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "MyDjangoProject.settings")
import django
from django.conf import settings
django.setup()

from myapp.models import MyModel
for s in MyModel.objects.all():
    print(s)
```