# "Rake" or my customs tasks in Django

Tags: python, django

In Rails I can create a custom a job for rake which does whatever I want to and then run it as "rake my_task". What's a way to do it in Django?

In particular, I need to create such a job which read my own data files in a custom format, processes the data in a special way and them inserts it into the db. And I'm going to run it multiple times, not only once. To achieve that I created a pure python script and ran it but got an error

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

So a python script didn't work, there must be a django-way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Django Way" would be to create a [custom command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-management-commands/).
If you want to create an external python script, then there is also a way to do that explained [in this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19475955/using-django-models-in-external-python-script) (EDIT: this is actually outdated for django 1.7) along with an example of how to create custom commands. I recommend the django documentation though if you're using the latest version of django.

On a related subject, check out [fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/).

#### Edit:

For a django >= 1.7 standalone script:

```
import os
import django
from myapp import models

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myapp.settings")
django.setup()

print models.MyModel.objects.get(pk=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to do it on top of my head

1 - You can write a custom management command to be invoked by `manage.py`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-management-commands/

2 - The rake equivalence in python world is pyinvoke: https://github.com/pyinvoke/invoke, which is a successor of fabric that takes some design inspiration from rake itself.

When using invoke, if you need the django environment to be setup, use this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/applications/#django.setup