# How to solve running sudo on manage.py causing a failure to connect to PSQL?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, psycopg2

So I followed the solution by `Burhan Khalid` from this stackoverflow thread: [Using Django models in external python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19475955/using-django-models-in-external-python-script) and have the following code in my `command.py`

```
import os
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError

from chat.models import Account, Client, Trader


class Command(BaseCommand):
     help = 'Does some magical work'

     def __str__(self):
        return "Your driver!"

     def handle(self, *args, **options):
         print(Client.objects.all())
```

which runs perfectly when I run the command `py manage.py command`
However, I'm trying to hook it up to a Twisted reactor thus needing me to run the project with sudo. Now when I do run `sudo py manage.py command`, it fails horribly on me with this as the last part of the error:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 164, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist
```

So I'm assuming running `sudo` messes up `psycopg2/psql`? Is there any way around this?

Here's my `settings.py` file:

```
>INSTALLED_APPS = (
>    'django.contrib.admin',
>    'django.contrib.auth',
>    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
>    'django.contrib.sessions',
>    'django.contrib.messages',
>    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
>    
>    'chat',
>)
>
>MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
>    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
>    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
>    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
>    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
>    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
>    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
>    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
>    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
>)

>ROOT_URLCONF = 'esdctest.urls'

>TEMPLATES = [
>    {
>        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
>        'DIRS': [],
>        'APP_DIRS': True,
>        'OPTIONS': {
>            'context_processors': [
>                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
>                'django.template.context_processors.request',
>                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
>                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
>            ],
>        },
>    },
>

>WSGI_APPLICATION = 'esdctest.wsgi.application'

>DATABASES = {
>    'default': {
>        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
>        'NAME': 'db',
>        'USER': '',
>        'PASSWORD': '',
>        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
>        'PORT': '5432',
>    }
>}

>LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

>TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

>USE_I18N = True

>USE_L10N = True

>USE_TZ = True

>STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Thanks

Comment: Share your settings.py with us

Comment: Just added my settings.py! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should fill `USER` field in your `DATABASES` dict. Like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'db',
        'USER': 'django',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Otherwise the name of the current user (e.g. `root`) will be used.

Comment: Sorry for the super late response! It worked, thanks! I appreciate it :)