# How to import model in Python/Django

Tags: python, django

My project structure is as follows:

```
my_proj
 ---calculation
 ---cardata
 ---master
 ---my_proj
     --- __init.py__
     --- admin.py
     --- settings.py
     --- url.py
     --- update_db_from_ftp.py  ///// This is my custom file
```

In **update_db_from_ftp.py** I want to download an csv file from ftp and update the database(if necessary) once every day with cron.

But the problem is that I can't import model which I want to update. The model which I want to update is inside `master` folder in `models.py` file.

I try to import model as follows:

```
from master.models import ModelName
```

But I'm getting an error as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "update_db_from_ftp.py", line 6, in <module>
    from master.models import ModelName
ImportError: No module named master.models
```

But I use the same model in `cardata` and `calculation` folder and I import it the same way as I try in `update_db_from_ftp.py` file, but there it works without problems.

Any idea how to solve it?

UDPATE

The structure of the master folder is as follows:

[image]

Comment: can you show the master structure also ?

Comment: @VikasDamodar Sure. See my updated question.

Comment: Why don't you write your script `update_db_from_ftp.py` as a management command. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-management-commands/

Comment: Use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19475955/using-django-models-in-external-python-script). This is what you are trying

Comment: Use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19475955/using-django-models-in-external-python-script). This is what you are trying.

Comment: I did it as `management command` and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For using django code in an arbitrary external script, two things are needed:

1. Django should be setup (exactly what happens when you run django shell).
2. The root project should be in python path (not the inner folder with same name).

Here is sample code which will work irrespective of the location of the script (although if the script is not one-off, better to add it as management command):

```
import django
import os
import sys

sys.path.append("/path/to/my-proj/")
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'my-proj.settings')
django.setup()

from master.models import ModelName

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(ModelName.objects.all())
```