# Unable to import model in my celery task

Tags: python, django, celery, supervisord

I'm running Celery/Django on my remote Ubuntu server via supervisor. My system can successfully receive and execute my 2 tasks from my `tasks.py`.

```
@periodic_task(run_every=timedelta(minutes=1))
def test_job():
    from polls.models import Question
    from post.models import Post #when I add this line, it fires the error
    for i in Question.objects.all():
        if i.question_text == "test":
            i.question_text = "not_test"
            i.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')


@periodic_task(name='run_scheduled_jobs', run_every=timedelta(seconds=30))
def run_scheduled_jobs():
    return True
```

However, when I use:

```
from post.models import Post
```

in my task, the task fails:

[image]

I've tried importing models from all my other modules and it works fine; e.g. `from Comment.models import Comment` and `from poll.models import Question` works fine. For some reason it's not letting me import `from post.models import Post`.

Here is the `post.models` file:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, User
from django.conf import settings
#from django.contrib.humanize import naturaltime
from django.apps import apps
from draft1.choices import CATEGORY_CHOICES
from django.utils import timezone
import requests
import tempfile
from django.core import files
from django.core.files import File as FileWrapper
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from math import log10
from urllib import parse
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import boto3
# import uuid
from functions.helper_functions import random_string
from math import log, exp
from draft1.choices import DURATION_CHOICES


class Post(models.Model):
    hash = models.CharField(max_length=18, default=random_string, null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    has_upvoted = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="has_upvoted", blank=True)
    has_downvoted = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="has_downvoted", blank=True)
    title = models.TextField(max_length=95)
    second_title = models.TextField(max_length=95, blank=True, null=True)
    dots1 = models.CharField(max_length=90, blank=True)
    dots2 = models.CharField(max_length=90, blank=True)
    dots3 = models.CharField(max_length=90, blank=True)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    content = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
    imageURL = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    video = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    entered_category = models.CharField(max_length=80, default='news')
    ad = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    total_comments = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    post_score = models.ForeignKey('post.PostScore', related_name='post_score', blank=True, null=True)
    hot = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def handle_uploaded_file(f, filename):
        with open('/tmp/%s' % filename, 'wb+') as destination:
            for chunk in f.chunks():
                destination.write(chunk)

    @property
    def video_source(self):
        if self.imageURL:
            t = urlparse(self.imageURL).netloc
            domain = '.'.join(t.split('.')[1:])
            if domain == "youtube.com":
                return "youtube"
            else:
                return "standard"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class AdvertisePost(Post):
    url = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    position = models.IntegerField(default=DURATION_CHOICES[2][0], choices=DURATION_CHOICES)
    duration = models.IntegerField(default=48)
    total_price = models.IntegerField(default=20)
    activated = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    counter = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class PostScore(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='score')
    upvotes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    downvotes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def hot(self):
        s = self.upvotes
        baseScore = log(max(s, 1))
        now = datetime.now()

        timeDiff = (now - self.post.date).days

        if (timeDiff > 1):
            x = timeDiff - 1
            baseScore = baseScore * exp(-8 * x * x)

        return baseScore


class Room(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=68)
    frequency = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    comments = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Any idea why it won't let me import `post.models`?

PS: The module `post.models` definately exists, and it works fine when I import it from my other files (e.g. `views.py` etc).

settings.py

```
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULER = "django_celery_beat.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler"
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'run_scheduled_jobs': {
        'task': 'run_scheduled_jobs', 
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=45),
    },
    'test_job': {
            'task': 'tasks.test_job',
            'schedule': timedelta(seconds=45),
    },
    'post_jobs': {
        'task': 'post.tasks.post_jobs',  
        'schedule': timedelta(minutes=1),
    },
    'test_post': {
        'task': 'post.tasks.test_post',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=45),
    }
}

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'post',
    ...
]
```

EDIT:

I've added `tasks.py` to my `post` module and changed my `settings.py` accordingly above:

**post/tasks.py**

```
@periodic_task(run_every=timedelta(minutes=1))
def test_post():
    from polls.models import Question
    from .models import Post
    for i in Post.objects.all():
        if i.entered_category == "test":
            i.entered_category = "not_test"
            i.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')


@periodic_task(name='post_jobs', run_every=timedelta(seconds=30)) # task name found! celery will do its job
def post_jobs():
    # do whatever stuff you do
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably your tasks.py file is not under a folder managed by django. I run this kind of issues when using django-dependent modules (as models) from outside the django project.

You have few of options:

Implement your tasks.py inside any of your django modules(apps), i.e:

```
  ├─┬ post
  │ ├── __init__.py
  │ ├── tasks.py
  │ ├── views.py
  │ └── urls.py
  └── otherapp
```

Create a module subfolder for your celery related logic inside the django project:

```
  ├─┬ celery
  │ ├── __init__.py
  │ └── tasks.py
  └── post
```

You could also Import django models into your `tasks.py` still being external to a django project. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19475955/5476782) question.

Mind the `__init__.py` file which is needed by python to load folder contents as a module.

I hope it helps!

**Update**

I see.
It is a best practive to set imports at the beginning of the file. You are loading `Post` in code that is executed in the shared memory of the celery workers. That is different from the memory managed by the django application.

Try doing your imports at the very begining of the file:

```
from polls.models import Question
from post.models import Post # added post here

@periodic_task(run_every=timedelta(minutes=1))
def test_post():        
    for i in Post.objects.all():
        if i.entered_category == "test":
            i.entered_category = "not_test"
            i.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')


@periodic_task(name='post_jobs', run_every=timedelta(seconds=30)) # task name found! celery will do its job
def post_jobs():
    # do whatever stuff you do
    return True
```

If is that the case it would work.

Comment: I created a `tasks.py` in my `post` module with the same tasks, however my celery cannot find the tasks. I also changed `app.autodiscover_tasks(['draft1', 'post'])` in my `draft1/celery.py` as the docs suggets when importing tasks from another module: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.html#celery.Celery.autodiscover_tasks - i've edited my post with the changes, any suggestions why it doesn't work? In my celery beat schedule in my settings I also tried changing `post.tasks.test_post` to `tasks.test_post` but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Still not working unfortunately. Celery can't find the function/module so your updated code doesn't really change anything.

Comment: Well, the last thing is to check other decorators, try the simpler `@task` or even, split it, and implement the celery logic without using the `django_celery_beat`